# Failed to load bundle error when adding native base import in react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I have a simple react app which I generated from react native cli,
when I add `native-base` import to my component and run the app by `react-native run-ios` I get the following error:

Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(Unable to resolve module `react-timer-mixin` from `/Users/wallet/Desktop/Projects/HomaWallet/node_modules/native-base/dist/src/basic/Tabs/index.js`: Module `react-timer-mixin` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`. (null))

__38-[RCTCxxBridge loadSource:onProgress:]_block_invoke.226
    RCTCxxBridge.mm:412

___ZL36attemptAsynchronousLoadOfBundleAtURLP5NSURLU13block_pointerFvP18RCTLoadingProgressEU13block_pointerFvP7NSErrorP9RCTSourceE_block_invoke.118

__80-[RCTMultipartDataTask 
URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:]_block_invoke

-[RCTMultipartStreamReader emitChunk:headers:callback:done:]

-[RCTMultipartStreamReader readAllPartsWithCompletionCallback:progressCallback:]

-[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:]

__88-[NSURLSession delegate_streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:completionHandler:]_block_invoke

-[NSBlockOperation main]
-[__NSOperationInternal _start:]
__NSOQSchedule_f
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_continuation_pop
_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke
_dispatch_root_queue_drain
_dispatch_worker_thread2
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread

React native version `0.58.1`

Native Base version `^2.10.0`

OS `Mac`

Comment: Did you tried restarting the bundler?...because it says that unable to resolve the module ,  This usually happens when we add a new library and run the app without restarting the bundler.

Comment: As @AkshayAggarwal says, most issues like this are caused by the bundler needing to be restarted this gist shows a tried and tested way to clear the cache https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d

Comment: didn't you try "npm i --save react-timer-mixin"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by downgrading react native version to `57.7` and native base version to  `2.8.1`

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade your native-base version to be at least 2.11.0, this is the version that the issue was fixed. You can find more details in their github under 2.11.0 release: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/releases

Answer (score 2):

Just add "react-timer-mixin": "0.13.4" to your package.json and install. 
This helped me for the same issue with react-native: 0.58.6 and native-base 2.8.1